# How do I download a file in Blazor server side?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I download a file from the server to the browser in Blazor?

I'm using Core 3.1.

I thought maybe I could somehow navigate to another page but I can't get that code to work either. It looks like Microsoft restructured the objects from the examples I could find online.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services
@inject IUriHelper UriHelper
```

Comment: Just use a link pointing to a web api method on you server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inject @NavigationHelper NavigationHelper instead of @inject IUriHelper IUriHelperfor to make it work.  Then in your method you call NavigationHelper.NavigateTo("URL here") for redirection.